# variadic pack and unpack in go lang: '[]string{f(v)}...'

Tags: go, variadic

I found this function while browsing github:

```
func Accumulate(s []string, f func(st string) string) (result []string) {
    for _, v := range s {
        result = append(result, []string{f(v)}...)
    }
    return result
}
```

Could this method be simplified to the following, or am I missing something:

```
func Accumulate(s []string, f func(st string) string) (result []string) {
    for _, v := range s {
        result = append(result, f(v))
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Yes, your version is much saner.

Comment: I wonder if the compiler optimizes the first example somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version you have written is correct and sane to understand. I wrote a benchmark:

```
package p

import (
    "testing"
    "strings"
)

var s = []string{"hello", "world", "this", "new", "world"}

func BenchmarkAcc1(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        Accumulate(s, strings.ToUpper)
    }
}

func BenchmarkAcc2(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        Accumulate2(s, strings.ToUpper)
    }
}
```

Here are a few results I got:

```
% go test -benchtime=10s -bench=.
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkAcc1   10000000          1510 ns/op
BenchmarkAcc2   10000000          1492 ns/op
ok      _/home/satran/test  33.064s
```

As you can see there is no performance gain either, in fact your version works better.

Here is the source:

```
package p

func Accumulate(s []string, f func(st string) string) (result []string) {
    for _, v := range s {
        result = append(result, []string{f(v)}...)
    }
    return result
}

func Accumulate2(s []string, f func(st string) string) (result []string) {
    for _, v := range s {
        result = append(result, f(v))
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Note: rather than running `go test -bench` repeatedly just (apparently) to eliminate noise you could have used something like `-benchtime=10s`.